# Simplest way to process multiple hardcoded values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I do this in SQL Server?  (I know it won't run as written but it illustrates the question better than I can explain)

```
SELECT SQRT(number) WHERE number IN (4,9,16,25)
```

It would return multiple rows of course

Answer (score 14):

you can use [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

```
select sqrt(number) 
from (
    values (4),(9),(16),(25)
) as T(number)
```

or use [union all](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

```
select sqrt(number)
from (
    select 4 union all
    select 9 union all
    select 16 union all
    select 25
) as T(number)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20826)</kbd>**

Comment: Nice, I have never seen this syntax before.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a derived table:

```
SELECT SQRT(number)
FROM (
    SELECT 4 AS number
    UNION ALL SELECT 9
    UNION ALL SELECT 16
    UNION ALL SELECT 25
) A
```

Comment: actually, it's better to use `union all` otherwise SQL server will try to avoid duplicates, this could decrease performance or actually remove duplicates and give incorrect results