# Insert last X Week Numbers into Temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, temp-tables

### My Question

I am trying to write a stored procedure that retrieves the week numbers for the past X weeks and then inserts them into a temporary table.

So far I have been able to create the temporary table and return the contents (not very hard). However, my issue now lies with the inserting of the last X week numbers into my temporary table... Do I use a loop of some sort? If so, how do I do this?

***Please note I cannot do a simple minus of the current week number because that could produce negatives if the current week number is less than X... The week number has to be calculated with `DATEPART` each time (I think).***

### What I have tried...

My code so far looks like this:

```
-- Declare the variables for the login totals
DECLARE @Current_Week_Number int

-- Get the current week number
SELECT @Current_Week_Number = DATEPART( wk, GETDATE())

-- Create the temporary table
CREATE TABLE #Number_Of_Logins (
    Week_Number tinyint,
    Number_Of_Logins int
)

-- Return the number of logins
SELECT * FROM #Number_Of_Logins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
declare @X int = 3

;with cte as (
     select 0 as num       
     union all
     select num + 1 from cte where num < @X - 1
)
select
    datepart(wk, dateadd(wk, -num, getdate()))
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20942)</kbd>**

The query consists of 2 parts. Part 1 is [recursive common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Basically what I need here is to build a table of numbers from 0 to @X - 1, like this:

```
 num
 0
 1
 2
```

After that, I need to calculate date like current date, current date - 1 week, current date - 2 week - so I use [dateadd()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function (note minus before num, I want to substract weeks). And now I just need to calculate week number by [datepart()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.

Comment: That looks great and looks like it works. Would you mind adding some comments so I can try and work out what is going on? My SQL skills are not too great... Also, could you explain why you have a `;` before the `with`, and also why you have 2 `select`'s? really appreciate your help, thanks! +1

Comment: @BenCarey added some explanation, feel free to ask. If you have some table with numbers, you can use it instead of cte. If you need hardcoded number of weeks, you can just use table value constructor - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833428/simplest-way-to-process-multiple-hardcoded-values-in-sql/18833491#18833491